# No funciona la clase Math

Tags: java, método, jtextfield

```
public double getStringToDouble(String x){
return Double.parseDouble(valorMod);
}

public String getDoubleToString(double x){
    cadena = String.valueOf(valorMod);
    return cadena;
}
```

Con esos metodos transformo de String a Double, para hacer una calculadora

```
 private void resta1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
  if(turno==1){
     double res= m.getStringToDouble(o.getValor1());
     double cos = Math.cos(res);
     txtvista.setText(m.getDoubleToString(cos));
  }
}
```

Con ese botón debería mostrarme en el jtextfield el calculo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Primera regla del programador: [Siempre es tu culpa](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/). La clase Math seguro que funciona a la perfección mas no la estás usando de manera adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getDoubleToString(double x){

    cadena = String.valueOf(valorMod);
    return cadena;
}
```

¿En este método no debería ser en vez de `valorMod` el parametro `x`?

Comment: muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta de eso !!! muchas gracias DazzelWazzel.

Comment: Nada hombre, votame porfa, saludos.